# MVC-How to set Display name for the checkbox based on value enter in the same view textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am creating an MVC application. I have a model that has boolean and display name for that and one textbox. The aim is whenever do some change in the textbox, that name should reflect in the checkbox display name.

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Account Number")]
[Display(Name = "Account Number")]
public string AccountNumber{ get; set; }


 [Display(Name = "You approving whatever you entered- Your enter AccountNumber is ")]
 [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "Please accept the Terms and Conditions by clicking the check the box!")]
 public bool TermsAndConditions { get; set; }
```

View:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })           
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsAndConditions)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TermsAndConditions)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TermsAndConditions)


    </div>
```

JS:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#AccountNumber").keyup(function () {
            var text= $("#AccountNumber").val();
            alert('You type: '+text);
            $("#TermsAndConditions").val(text);
            });
        });
```

When I run the page, I am able to print the text whatever I do changes in the account number. But I am not able to assign the value to the checkbox display value. Please help me.

Comment: You should be updating the label text (the display attribute name value is what is put into the label) - not the checkbox, therefore you need to give your label a class / id you can target or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $("#TermsAndConditions").html(text);
```

try this it worked for me. Since only input type can use value.